# Запретить передвижение ячеек в uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

у меня есть две секции - первая секция (indexPath.section == 0), в ней можно редактировать ячейки и передвигать их, 
и вторая секция (indexPath.section == 1), в ней нельзя редактировать ячейки

проблема в том, что сейчас можно взять ячейки из первой секции и передвинуть ее во вторую секцию, это надо запретить 
как мне это сделать ?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return indexPath.section == 0;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
else{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

}

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return indexPath.section == 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение оказалось очень лаконичным

```
   - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
   if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != 0)
   {
       return sourceIndexPath;
   }

   return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

самы простой способ, это просто определить- можно двигать или нет:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return (indexPath.section == 1) ? NO : YES;
}
```